# Show image in Cell after viewDidLoad using didSelect method

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a cell with an empty UIImageView and a collectionView nested within containing a row of images. I made a didSelect function that I want to highlight the selected row and show it's image inside of the empty UIImageView.

I tried the reloadData function and the app crashed. I tried it without the reloadData function and the index path's item only highlights.

```swift
class DisplayImageCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let displayCell = "DisplayImageCell"

    let imageContainer: UIImageView = {
        let imageContainer = UIImageView()
        imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        imageContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "ic_person_outline_white_2x").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)))
        imageContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageContainer
    }()

    let pictureCollection: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        let imageContainer = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        imageContainer.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        imageContainer.tintColor = .yellow
        imageContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageContainer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear

        pictureCollection.dataSource = self
        pictureCollection.delegate = self
        pictureCollection.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: displayCell)

        addSubview(imageContainer)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            imageContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.80),
            imageContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
            ])

        addSubview(pictureCollection)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pictureCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            pictureCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            pictureCollection.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
            ])

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: displayCell, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        let imageOption = ImageOption(rawValue: indexPath.row)
        cell.iconImageView.image = imageOption?.icon()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: pictureCollection.frame.height, height: pictureCollection.frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: true)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: false)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: true)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: false)
    }

    private class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
            let iv = UIImageView()
            iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            iv.clipsToBounds = true
            iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return iv
        }()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: .zero)

            backgroundColor = .blue

            addSubview(iconImageView)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor),
                iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
                iconImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                iconImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
                ])

        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
    func updateCell(having indexPath: IndexPath, selected: Bool) {

        let selectedBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 211/255.0, blue: 241/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let defaultBackgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        let imageSlot = DisplayImageCell()
        let ep = EditProfileController()

        if let cell = pictureCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? selectedBackgroundColor : defaultBackgroundColor
            imageSlot.imageContainer.image = UIImage(named: "ThumbsUp")
            ep.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result are for the Empty Imageview to display the image of the selected indexPath.row. I find a fatal error of nil value when I try to reload collectionView.

Comment: Why do you create these two new instances `let imageSlot = DisplayImageCell()` and
`let ep = EditProfileController()`?

Comment: @NickBurinok the profile controller is the class housing the CollectionView that generates this cell. I call an instance of DisplayImageCell because the function was created inside a private class and in order to reference the Empty UIImageView I had to call imageSlot.

Comment: the thing is that you are not actually getting a reference to the existing class, but creating a new instance of it.

Comment: @NickBurinok Thank you for that bit of information. For some reason I thought that I  had to make the reference in the new function when all I had to do was pull the same info I used to generate the images for the cells instead of trying to pull the info from the cells themselves

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show a selected image from the data source of the collection view in the `imageContainer` you can just fetch the image in the `didSelectItemAt indexPath` as you do in the `cellForItemAt indexPath`:

```
let imageOption = ImageOption(rawValue: indexPath.item)
```

then

```
imageContainer.image = imageOption?.icon()
```

there is no actual need in calling `reloadData()` as the data source for the collection view has not been updated.